# Retornar valores pré-definidos dependendo de condição lógica

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho o seguinte *script* de MySQL:

```
SELECT con.id_crecpa,
    con.id_crecpa,
    con.descricao,
    con.diabase,
    con.dt_emissao,
    con.dt_quitacao 
FROM crecpa con
INNER JOIN pessoa pes ON con.id_pessoa = pes.id_pessoa
INNER JOIN plano_conta pla ON con.id_plano_conta = pla.id_plano_conta        
WHERE con.id_empresa = 6
AND con.dt_vencto < CURDATE()
```

Se a data do registro for menor que a data atual, quero retornar mais uma coluna com o valor "vencido", como posso fazer isso?

Edit: na verdade, vou precisar mais que isso, vou precisar retornar 'vencido', 'vence hoje' e 'a vencer', já sei que terei q usar o `CASE WHEN`, e tentei dessa forma:

```
SELECT con.id_crecpa,
    con.id_crecpa,
    con.descricao,
    con.diabase,
    con.dt_emissao,
    con.dt_vencto,  
    CASE con.diabase
       WHEN con.dt_vencto < CURDATE() THEN 'vencido'
       WHEN con.dt_vencto > CURDATE() THEN 'a vencer'
       WHEN con.dt_vencto = CURDATE() THEN 'vence hoje'      
    END AS venc 
FROM crecpa con
INNER JOIN pessoa pes ON con.id_pessoa = pes.id_pessoa
INNER JOIN plano_conta pla ON con.id_plano_conta = pla.id_plano_conta        
WHERE con.id_empresa = 6
AND con.dt_vencto < CURDATE()
AND con.tipo = "Credito"
AND con.status = "Ativo"
```

porem veio `NULL`.

Resultado

```
id_crecpa  id_crecpa  descricao    diabase  dt_emissao  dt_vencto   venc    
---------  ---------  -----------  -------  ----------  ----------  --------
       87         87  Mensalidade       10  2018-01-12  2018-01-10  (NULL)
```

Comment: A coluna vc tem que retornar sempre... O que muda é o valor, procure pelo case when

Comment: Atualizei a resposta depois da sua [edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/268905/revisions) com algumas observações. FIca a sugestão de nas próximas perguntas já colocar o problema completo se possível, para não invalidar respostas dadas.

Answer (score 4):

## Controle de Fluxo com MySQL

O MySQL possui quatro operadores de fluxo (cinco se notar que o `CASE` tem duas formas, uma parecida com o `if` das linguagens de programação, e outra parecida com o `switch`:

```
CASE        Forma 1: CASE WHEN condição THEN valor ... ELSE ... END;
CASE        Forma 2: CASE expressao WHEN v1 THEN e1 WHEN v2 THEN e2 ... END;
IF()        IF( expressão lógica, valor se verdadeiro, valor se falso );
IFNULL()    IFNULL( e1, e2 ) - Se e1 for nulo, retorna e2, senão retorna e1;
NULLIF()    NULLIF( e1, e2 ) - Se e1==e2, retorna NULL, senão retorna e1;
```

Mais detalhes no manual:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html

### Usando a funçao `IF` no seu caso específico:

O MySQL tem a função `IF`, que facilita muito a leitura da *query* (em T-SQL tem o IIF, que é equivalente). Aplicando à primeira parte da pergunta:

```
SELECT con.id_crecpa,
    con.descricao,
    con.diabase,
    con.dt_emissao,
    con.dt_quitacao,
    IF( con.dt_vencto < CURRENT_DATE, 'vencido', '-' ) AS status
FROM crecpa con
INNER JOIN pessoa pes ON con.id_pessoa = pes.id_pessoa
INNER JOIN plano_conta pla ON con.id_plano_conta = pla.id_plano_conta        
WHERE con.id_empresa = 6;
```

Note que tirei o último `AND` senão você não vai notar o efeito do `IF`. E se a *query* for realmente só isso aí, me parece que tem `JOIN`s desnecessários.

**Aninhando `IF`s**

Mesmo [depois da edição da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/268905/revisions) o `IF` ainda fica simples, bastando dois deles para resolver as 3 condições:

```
    IF( con.dt_vencto < CURRENT_DATE, 'vencido',
       IF( con.dt_vencto > CURRENT_DATE, 'a vencer', 'vence hoje' )
    ) AS status
```

Neste caso, o segundo `IF` entra como segundo argumento do primeiro, sendo usado apenas no caso da data não ser menor que a atual.

Pode expandir conforme a necessidade:

```
    IF( condicao1, 'valor pra condicao 1',
       IF( condicao2, 'valor pra condicao 2',
          IF( condicao3, 'valor pra condicao 3',
             'valor caso nenhuma das 3 satisfaça'
          )
       )
    ) AS status
```

### Equivalente com `CASE`:

Se ainda assim prefere usar o `CASE`, bastam dois `WHEN`, pois a terceira condição é a única restante caso as duas primeiras comparações sejam falsas. Neste caso se usa o `ELSE`:

```
       CASE
          WHEN con.dt_vencto < CURRENT_DATE THEN 'vencido'
          WHEN con.dt_vencto > CURRENT_DATE THEN 'a vencer'
          ELSE 'vence hoje'      
       END
       AS status
```

**Pontos de interesse:**

No MySQL a função `IF` tem três parâmetros:

```
 IF( expressão lógica, valor se verdadeiro, valor se falso )
```

E toda coluna do SELECT pode receber um apelido com a palavra chave `AS`. Exemplo:

```
 SELECT nome AS meunome
```

Juntando as duas coisas, chegamos nisto para a coluna do "vencido":

```
IF( con.dt_vencto < CURRENT_DATE, 'vencido', '-' ) AS status
            se preferir pode deixar em branco ^       ^ e aqui vc escolhe o nome
```

Só de curiosidade, usei o valor predefinido CURRENT_DATE no lugar da função CURDATE() para mostrar outra alternativa de sintaxe, ambos resultam na mesma coisa.

Comment: Perfeito, consegui resolver meu problema tenho só uma dúvida, naquele caso onde você usa o `CASE` você cria uma nova coluna chamada 'status', certo? Teria como atribuir aqueles valores a uma coluna já existente?

Comment: Não estamos criando, estamos apelidando só para ficar mais fácil recuperar/identificar o valor. Pode tirar o `AS status` que  funciona normalmente. O `IF`  e o `CASE`  nestes exemplos retornam valor, então um `UPDATE tabela SET campo = IF( idade > 17, 'maior', 'menor' )` funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Veja aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7859f/1

Answer (score 1):

consegui resolver, ficou dessa forma(retirei o nome do campo que estava logo apos a palavra CASE):

```
 SELECT con.id_crecpa,
        con.id_crecpa,
        con.descricao,
        con.diabase,
        con.dt_emissao,
        con.dt_vencto,  
           CASE
           WHEN con.dt_vencto < CURDATE() THEN 'vencido'
           WHEN con.dt_vencto > CURDATE() THEN 'a vencer'
           WHEN con.dt_vencto = CURDATE() THEN 'vence hoje'      
           END AS venc  
    FROM crecpa con
    INNER JOIN pessoa pes ON con.id_pessoa = pes.id_pessoa
    INNER JOIN plano_conta pla ON con.id_plano_conta = pla.id_plano_conta        
    WHERE con.id_empresa = 6
    AND con.dt_vencto < CURDATE()
    AND con.tipo = "Credito"
    AND con.status = "Ativo
```

Comment: Conforme comentei anteriormente, com o AND con.dt_vencto < CURDATE() você só vai ver a palavra "vencido". Vale notar que o seu terceiro WHEN é desnecessário (vide minha resposta).