# Resultado de uma procura MYSQL em linha, não coluna

Tags: mysql

Bom dia. Possuo uma tabela que lista uma série de motivos cada vez que eles acontecem. Estou usando um `select` para agrupar esses motivos e ter como resultado os 5 mais recorrentes. Esse é o meu código:

```
SELECT count(*) as NumeroDeVezes, motivos FROM relatoriomotivos GROUP BY motivos ORDER BY NumeroDeVezes DESC LIMIT 5
```

O problema é que eu necessitava que a resposta fosse uma linha só para os motivos e uma linha só para o número de vezes, enquanto estou recebendo uma coluna para os motivos e outra para o número de vezes. Existe alguma forma de ajustar isso?

Comment: Você realmente precisa que seja em linhas separadas ? Qual o impacto?

Comment: Infelizmente sim, estou usando essas informações para a programação de um gráfico e ele só aceita a entrada em linha.

Comment: No SQL Server dá para fazer isso usando `PIVOT` como subselect, mas aparentemente o mysql não tem isso, [você precisaria construir algo que seja reutilizável](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html) para não precisar mudar a query toda vez que um motivo novo for incluído.

Answer (score 3):

Não é uma solução completa, mas já é um ponto de partida.

<sub>Se conseguir fazer uma amostra dos dados no SQL Fiddle, e dar mais detalhes na pergunta, posso editar a resposta e elaborar melhor</sub>

Se o número de colunas for fixo, pode usar o `IF` para calcular:

```
SELECT
   SUM( IF( motivo='A'), 1, 0 ) AS motivo_a,
   SUM( IF( motivo='B'), 1, 0 ) AS motivo_b,
   SUM( IF( motivo='C'), 1, 0 ) AS motivo_c,
   SUM( IF( motivo='D'), 1, 0 ) AS motivo_d,
   SUM( IF( motivo='E'), 1, 0 ) AS motivo_e
FROM
   motivos
```

Caso alguém precise da solução para outros DBs que não tenham suporte à função `IF`, dá para fazer o mesmo com `CASE`.

Veja este post para mais detalhes:

> [Controle de fluxo com MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/268907/70)

Para os títulos, infelizmente também teria que ser manual. O `UNION`permite gerar as duas linhas, uma com título, outra com contagem:

```
SELECT 'Motivo A', 'Motivo B', 'Motivo C'
UNION
SELECT
   SUM( IF( motivo='A'), 1, 0 ),
   SUM( IF( motivo='B'), 1, 0 ),
   SUM( IF( motivo='C'), 1, 0 )
```

Outra coisa que pode interessar é o `GROUP_CONCAT`, que traz vários resultados em uma linha só, mas aí já não seriam colunas separadas. Seria uma coluna com dados separados por vírgula.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode trabalhar o resultado de sua consulta como string, de forma a possibilitar sua manipulação sem precisar presumir sua existência de forma "hard-coded".

Utilize a função de agregação [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) para "fundir" em uma linha cada coluna de sua consulta, usando o separador que preferir (aqui estou usando `;`):

```
select 
    GROUP_CONCAT(motivo SEPARATOR ';') as motivos,
    GROUP_CONCAT(numero SEPARATOR ';') as numeros
from (
  select count(*) as numero, motivo from motivos 
  group by motivo order by numero desc limit 5
) tmp;

 ***
|                                      motivos |   numeros |
|----------------------------------------------|-----------|
| motivo 1;motivo 2;motivo 3;motivo 4;motivo 5 | 3;3;3;3;1 |
```

Depois, para que cada coluna retorne em uma linha, concatene-as novamente, utilizando com um caractere de quebra de linha `\n` entre elas. Uso aqui a função [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) por permitir definir o separador geral no início, possibilitando a inclusão de mais linhas de forma elegante, sem ter que ficar repetindo o `\n`:

```
select 
  CONCAT_WS (
    '\n',
    GROUP_CONCAT(motivo SEPARATOR ';'),
    GROUP_CONCAT(numero SEPARATOR ';')
   ) as resultado
from (
  select count(*) as numero, motivo from motivos 
  group by motivo order by numero desc limit 5
) tmp;

 ***
|                                              resultado |
|--------------------------------------------------------|
| motivo 1;motivo 2;motivo 3;motivo 4;motivo 5
3;3;3;3;1 |
```

Perceba que o resultado é apenas uma coluna de um registro, com quebra de linha entre o grupo de motivos e o grupo de números.

Caso você queira dois registros, um para cada grupo, acredito que um UNION resolva o problema, com um pouco de redundância. Seria mais elegante se o MySQL suportasse Common Table Expressions, mas [isso só virá na versão 8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), portanto segue exemplo com UNION:

```
select 
    GROUP_CONCAT(motivo SEPARATOR ';') as resultado
from (
  select count(*) as numero, motivo from motivos 
  group by motivo order by numero desc limit 5
) tmp
UNION 
select 
    GROUP_CONCAT(numero SEPARATOR ';') as resultado
from (
  select count(*) as numero, motivo from motivos 
  group by motivo order by numero desc limit 5
) tmp;

 ***
|                                    resultado |
|----------------------------------------------|
| motivo 1;motivo 2;motivo 3;motivo 4;motivo 5 |
|                                    3;3;3;3;1 |
```

Segue SQL Fiddle contendo os exemplos acima: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/644b0b/26

---

Dito isso, só para fins complementares, o UNION com uso de CTE ficaria assim:

```
with consulta as (
  select 
      GROUP_CONCAT(motivo SEPARATOR ';') as motivos,
      GROUP_CONCAT(numero SEPARATOR ';') as numeros
  from (
    select count(*) as numero, motivo from motivos 
    group by motivo order by numero desc limit 5
  ) tmp
)
select motivos from consulta 
union
select numeros from consulta;
```