# Condição para o INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, mariadb, innodb

Preciso que o SQL Confira se na '@variavel' enviada existe algum valor igual a 1, 2 ou 3; Caso seja verdeiro insira o valor 1, do contrario insira o valor 0.

Obs: a tabela e coluna podem ser dadas de exemplo como fictícias.

Comment: Em qual banco de dados? O SQL em si não aceita isto de forma padrão, mas extensões da linguagem de um banco de dados pode aceitar, provavelmente deveráa ser em uma *stored procedure*.

Comment: Assim como o seu script de `INSERT`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente isso:

```
INSERT INTO tabela SET coluna = IF( @variavel IN (1,2,3), 1, 0 );
```

- O `IN` retorna verdadeiro se a variável estiver na lista
- O `IF` retorna o segundo valor se a primeira expressão for verdade, senão retorna o terceiro.

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1093dd/1)**.

Notas:

- Em T-SQL a partir do 2012, existe a função `IIF`, que funciona da mesma forma que o `IF` do MySQL/MariaDB
- Para outros DBs tem o `CASE`, pode ver mais detalhadamente neste post:

  > [Retornar valores pré-definidos dependendo de condição lógica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/268905/70)

Answer (score 2):

Usando SQL Ansi, que funciona em todos os bancos de dados, você pode fazer algo como:

```
insert into dados (coluna1) values (
case @parametro 
   when 1 then 1
   when 2 then 1
   when 3 then 1
   else 0
end)
```